# Simplification of: A’(BC + AB + BA’) in boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am trying to understand the simplification of the boolean expression:

A’(BC + AB + BA’)

I was wondering if someone could show me the steps needed to do this. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First distribute $A'$:
$$A'BC+A'AB+A'BA'$$
By idempotence and annihilation this is equal to
$$A'BC+A'B$$
Then by absorption on $A'B$ we get the final result as
$$A'B$$